# Image not showing in google sheets from google form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

When ever I upload an image from google forms it shows the result as a URL.  How can I get google sheets to show the image that was uploaded instead of the URL?

Answer (score 1):

As standard google sheets will not display a URL as an image, you will need to add an additional formula for this.

```
=IMAGE(url, [mode], [height], [width])
```

> [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en)

As an example if you have a google form outputting URLs to column A, using something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A = "","",IMAGE(A:A)))
```

In column B will display the image in column B.

[image: Example Sheet]